# .net dictionary object type

Tags: .net, dictionary

I'm trying to use a dll on my system. One of the methods return a dictionary object defined in the object browser as

```
"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<<string,1.5>>"
```

What is 1.5? Or is that some security mechanism to lock the dll from unintended use?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Blorgbeard

Comment: What can you see in the object browser when you expand the dictionary? What is the declared return type of the method?

Comment: @svik. Well if I expand the object I can see that the Dictionary in turn contains a KeyvaluePair which in turns contains a List, etc. A pretty deep hierarchy. But I don't know how to assign this object since I can't use 1.5 as a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"1.5" is not a valid type name in any common .NET language, they insist you start a type name with a letter.  Important to make the job of a lexer simple, the part of the compiler that preprocesses the source code into tokens before the program is parsed.  A lexer will identify "1.5" as a number, not an identifier.

The CLR has much more lax rules about that however, just about anything goes for a type name.  This is taken advantage of by *obfuscators*.  A program that you run after building an assembly that makes it difficult to reverse-engineer the source code from the assembly.  There are several very good decompilers available for .NET, like Reflector and ILSpy.  An obfuscator is designed to defeat them.

High odds that the assembly you are using was obfuscated.

Comment: Do you mean that while `1.5` is not a valid type name for .NET compiler/parser, it is valid for .NET runtime?

Comment: @SinaIravanian I think Hans meant exactly what he said, that `1.5` is not valid in most common .Net languages (C#, VB.NET, F#, …). But it is valid name in IL.